# Shortcode Help Needed → attributes

Tags: shortcode

```
function the_image($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "to" => 'https://pics.wikifeet.com/Melania-Trump-Feet-720891.jpg'
    ), $atts));
    return '<div class="class1">';
        return '<img class="class2" src="'.$to.'" alt="The First Caption" width="100%" height="auto">';
        return '<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>;'
    return '</div>';
}
add_shortcode("the_image", "the_image");
```

Please help me If you think I am missing any sanitization.
secondly,

How should I print attribute in the shortcode I mean the image link needs to be entered by the user. I have put the default →  `"to" =>`'https://pics.wikifeet.com/Melania-Trump-Feet-720891.jpg'

but this needs to be changed. please guide me.

Comment: Do you think that this is faulty → ` src="'.$to.'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning each line individually. It's only going to output the first line since `return` stops execution of the function. Instead, add each line to a string by concatenating with `.=`:

```
function wpse_276152_image_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'to' => 'https://pics.wikifeet.com/Melania-Trump-Feet-720891.jpg'
    ), $atts );

    $output = '<div class="class1">';
    $output .= '<img class="class2" src="' . $atts['to'] . '" alt="The First Caption" width="100%" height="auto">';
    $output .= '<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'the_image', 'wpse_276152_image_shortcode' );
```

`.=` is the same as saying `$output = $output . ' string to add'`.

Also note some other changes I made:

1. `the_image` is too generic a name for a function. You're increasing your chances of running into conflict issues. Note that the function name and shortcode don't need to be the same.
2. Don't use `extract()`. As your code gets more complex it can [make maintenance needlessly difficult.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/829454/2684861)

Comment: this line → `), $atts) );` is showing some bugs.

Comment: one `)` was extra.

Comment: If I am putting it like this →`the_image` in my Wordpress editor then it's not working actually.

Comment: In the front-end, it is getting [published](https://www.screencast.com/t/5PUn1gQWLdZS) like this. And my [code looks like this](https://www.screencast.com/t/HEIysefwkeOF).

Comment: You there or disappeared?

Comment: Mate I'm not on call. If you need real time help, hire someone. As for you question: the code is correct. If the shortcode itself is appearing then either you're putting it somewhere that doesn't support shortcodes, or not registering it correctly because this code is in the wrong place. Otherwise, the code is correct.